# Sliding elements in c# UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp, slide

I have a question about animations in UWP. I want to have a menu on the bottom of my app that, when tapped on the top, slides up (shows) or down (hides almost entirely). I was learning WPF before and there I know I can use ThicknessAnimation to move the margin of my control and have it slide. Unfortunately, in UWP I can't use ThicknessAnimations, so I tried to find another way. I want this to work for an arbitrary FrameworkElement (so as to be able to reuse it). Eventually, I came up with this solution:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a vertical slide animation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storyboard">The storyboard to add the animation to</param>
    /// <param name="seconds">The time the animation will take</param>
    /// <param name="offset">The distance the element will cover (nagative is up, positive is down)</param>
    public static void AddVerticalSlide(this Storyboard storyboard, FrameworkElement element, float seconds, double offset)
    {

        var slideAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();       

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
        {
            double scalar = (double)i / 100;
            slideAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
            {                   
                Value = new Thickness(0, scalar*offset, 0, -scalar*offset),
                KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(scalar*seconds),
            });
        }   

        //slideAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

        // Set the target and target property
        Storyboard.SetTarget(slideAnimation, element);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideAnimation, "(FrameworkElement.Margin)");

        // Add the animation to the storyboard
        storyboard.Children.Add(slideAnimation);
    }
```

It works, looks nice, but here's the reason I'm asking this question: I don't know if it's proper. My guees is that there's a better way to slide objects than manually define 100 points on the way and move the object to each point using this animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but is just not the ideal way to *offset* an element. Why? Because you are creating two many `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`s when you really just need *one* `DoubleAnimation`.

You should almost never animate the `Margin` of an element. To change its position, a better approach is to animate the translate values (i.e. `TranslateX`/`TranslateY`) of its transform (`RenderTransform`) instead.

Animating anything in transform is efficient. They are off the UI thread. Traditionally, they were running in a special thread called *Compositor* thread (I think), but ever since the *Creators Update*, they have become even more performant according to the [Windows UI team](https://twitter.com/WindowsUI/status/829448451498741760) -

> When you use Storyboard and Transition animations in XAML, you’re
>   using Composition under the hood. Animations run at 60 frames per
>   second!

The following is an example of using such technique

```
public static void Slide(this UIElement target, Orientation orientation, double? from, double to, int duration = 400, int startTime = 0, EasingFunctionBase easing = null)
{
    if (easing == null)
    {
        easing = new ExponentialEase();
    }

    var transform = target.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    if (transform == null)
    {
        transform = new CompositeTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
    target.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

    var db = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = to,
        From = from,
        EasingFunction = easing,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration)
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(db, target);
    var axis = orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? "X" : "Y";
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(db, $"(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Translate{axis})");

    var sb = new Storyboard
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime)
    };

    sb.Children.Add(db);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

Note as performant as this approach gets, there is even more powerful animation support in UWP, thanks to the new Composition API. But offset animation in Composition can be a bit [tricky](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/wiki/XAML-Composition-Interop-Behavior-Changes).

However, the *UWP Community Tookit* has done a great job wrapping some useful animations like `Blur`, `Offset`, etc. Feel free to check [them](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) out.