# How to create a Turning animation?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

I want to make a turning animation to show the vehicle turning in Junction. Also, I want to do it with c#(code behind) because my vehicles are dynamically added.

**Solution tried:**

I tried to use TranslateTransform and RotateTransform but I could only create sharp turn animation. I want to create a smooth turn animation.

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Sample Code**

```
//Code to add car
private void Click1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myCar = new Image()
    {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/RedCar.png")),
        Width = 140,
        Height = 65,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform()
        {
            X = 0,
            Y = actualHeight / 2 - 145
        }
    };
    VehicleGrid.Children.Add(myCar);
}

//Code to create forward animation
private void MoreForward(UIElement element)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3)),
        To = LeftRoad.ActualWidth - 140
    };

    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, element.RenderTransform);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "X");
    storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

**Full Code**

You can see my full code in Github: [TrafficManagementSystem](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/TrafficManagementSystem/tree/master)

Comment: You could follow a path : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-animations-overview

Comment: @Aybe I think Path Animations is not available in UWP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an interesting [post](http://studentguru.gr/b/kaisaras89/archive/2013/02/23/enabling-an-element-to-animate-on-a-path-on-windows-8-store-apps-i-e-making-a-pathlistbox-layoutpath-for-windows-rt) that details how to create a layout path where your object can move along with.

But in a simple scenario like yours, you basically just want a *curved motion* like what's described in [this](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/choreography.html#choreography-continuity) Android's *Material Design Guideline*. Yeah... Android's, as we don't have native curved motion API support just yet (the Windows UI team did mention that they are looking to support this in the future though).

However, it's not too difficult to create your own curved motion. In fact, many have used this trick on the web already - apply the **opposite** speed of an *easing* on each axis. Also in your case, you will want the curve of the easing to be sharp in order to produce a nice turning animation.

For example, for a car coming from left to right and then doing a left turn, you can apply a `QuinticEase` with `EaseIn` mode on *x-axis* and one with `EaseOut` on *y-axis*. To turn the vehicle, just apply another rotation animation to it but with a short delay and lesser duration to ensure the turning only happens at the crossroad.

By slightly modifying my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485321/sliding-elements-in-c-sharp-uwp/45486302#45486302), you can achieve what I described above with the following code

**The `AnimateTransform` helper method**

```
public static void AnimateTransform(this UIElement target, string propertyToAnimate, Orientation? orientation, double? from, double to, int duration = 3000, int startTime = 0, EasingFunctionBase easing = null)
{
    if (easing == null)
    {
        easing = new ExponentialEase();
    }

    var transform = target.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    if (transform == null)
    {
        transform = new CompositeTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = transform;
    }
    target.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

    var db = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = to,
        From = from,
        EasingFunction = easing,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration)
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(db, target);

    var axis = string.Empty;
    if (orientation.HasValue)
    {
        axis = orientation.Value == Orientation.Horizontal ? "X" : "Y";
    }
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(db, $"(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.{propertyToAnimate}{axis})");

    var sb = new Storyboard
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime)
    };

    sb.Children.Add(db);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

**Create the turning animations**

```
MyCar.AnimateTransform("Translate", Orientation.Horizontal, null, -600, duration: 3000, easing: new QuinticEase
{
    EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn
});
MyCar.AnimateTransform("Translate", Orientation.Vertical, null, -600, duration: 3000, easing: new QuinticEase
{
    EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
});
MyCar.AnimateTransform("Rotation", null, null, -90, duration: 2000, startTime: 500);
```

**Result in motion**

[image]

Alternatively, you can replace the traditional `Storyboard` animation with the new *Composition API*, which provides fully customizable easing functions (see below), but the idea is the same.

```
public static CubicBezierEasingFunction EaseOutExpo(this Compositor compositor) =>
    compositor.CreateCubicBezierEasingFunction(new Vector2(0.14f, 1f), new Vector2(0.34f, 1f));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will have more than 20 cars at a time. Each car will be moving in its own path. Does using traditional Storyboard reduce performance in this scenario?

Comment: Nope, `Storyboard` is already very efficient and performant. 20 cars is really nothing.

Comment: I am testing your code. I will mark as answer after testing. Also, one more question, can we use [ExpressionAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.ExpressionAnimation) to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think EA is suitable in this case.

Comment: Can you post this code in GitHub? I would like to see your full code.

Comment: How can a UIElement have a custom defined method? In other words, how can I use `MyCar.AnimateTransform`?

Comment: Ah, you just place the extension method in a `ststic` helper class.

Comment: works great except setting `null` in `From` cause animation to start from 0,0

Comment: `null` is there for a purpose - when you don't care about the start position and just want it to resume from where it left off (from last time). If you it to start from somewhere, just give it a value.

Comment: Exactly, But It does not resume from where it left off. It starts from 0,0

Comment: It happens only for the initial Animation. You can see my code [here](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/TrafficManagementSystem)

Comment: I am not sure if I get you. For the first time, if you want it to start from somewhere, you need to give `from` a value, right? After that, you just use `null`. Make sense?

Comment: Fixed. Initially, I used `TranslateTransform` to place the car on the road. It seems changing it to `CompositeTransform` during animation breaks the `X` and `Y` position. Now I fixed by using `CompositeTransform` to place the car on the road. Thank you very much. I would like to see this helper method in a NuGet Package.

Comment: Good job. :) Yes the helper method relies on *one instance* of a `CompositeTransform`.